# Number of ways to visit each cell of $n\times n$ board once

Tags: combinatorics, asymptotics

A piece lies on the upper-left corner of an $n\times n$ board. Let $f(n)$ denote the number of ways to move the pieces one step horizontally/vertically at a time, so that it visits each field of the board once.

How fast does $f(n)$ grow? What are upper/lower bounds we can get on $f(n)$?

Comment: See [here](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~itai/publications/Algorithms/Hamilton-paths.pdf).